# how to get role entities instead of user's role in Asp.net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented `Asp.net core 3.1 Identity` and I executed the line below to get the role. This gives me only names. But I want to get the role entities and show the list in the dropdown list. 
Is that possible to get id and name of the roles?

```
 var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(userIdentity);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly query the database to get current user's role id and role name .

Inject `ApplicationDbContext` to your controller :

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _applicationDbContext;

public HomeController(ApplicationDbContext applicationDbContext)
{

    _applicationDbContext = applicationDbContext;
}
```

Create Role class :

```
public class Role {
    public string  ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And query the roles like :

```
if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var userid = User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).FirstOrDefault().Value;
    var query = from b in _applicationDbContext.UserRoles
                where b.UserId == userid
                join p in _applicationDbContext.Roles
                    on b.RoleId equals p.Id into grouping
                from p in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new Role { ID=p.Id, Name=p.Name };

    var roles = query.ToList();
}
```